# Creating a "catch all" for URLs with Python's Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to create custom URLs for each user on my site.
My application uses certain custom URLs for its internal pages:

```
/login
/gallery
/about
etc ...
```

How can I make a url that would come after the above urls, and supply a function urlLookup() with the string it contains? And would I have to declare this at the end of my views file?

For example:

```
/First-Last
```

And how could I extend this to multiple variables?

```
/First-Last/contact
/First-Last/album/photo-title
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [url variables](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#url-route-registrations):

```
@app.route("/<full_name>")
def profile(full_name):
    # Lookup user by full name


@app.route("/<full_name>/<action>", defaults={"action": "contact"})
def act_on_user(full_name, action):
    # Lookup user and act on them
```